# Animation not playing

Tags: animation

I set the key points for my animation and it still doesn't play. I have tried changing the animation player and it still doesn't work. the fps becomes red when I hit play and nothing happens. Help asap.

Comment: What does the FPS counter say? Does it have a moving number or is it locked at 0?

Comment: could you please share your `.blend` file to be able to provide help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what you need to do, is set the end value at the bottom to the end keyframe that you have.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer? Add some screenshots maybe.